# "delete" feature isn't working for comments

Tags: bug, status-norepro

That's it... I can't delete *any* comments I post; even though the button is there.

**Update:** It doesn't work anywhere on *Writers'* and I can't try it anywhere else, unfortunately.

The *"delete"* link is there but it does nothing when I click it. That's true for all comments and answers I post.

---

> Alright, how does ***that*** not conform to quality standards? It
>   keeps telling me so with no links to solution so I'm guessing it's a
>   character length issue. With this note in the body, it should post...
>
> **Update:** It's a length issue... Any thoughts? Beside the original
>   question?

Comment: I just posted and deleted a comment here.  Where is the comment that you can't delete?

Comment: Were you able to delete comments before this? On both writers and meta.writers? How about on other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Hello! Are you still experiencing this?

Comment: @Aarthi, No. It got sorted out around late May '12. Should I edit to make this clear?

Comment: @Mussri Nope, this message is enough. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Well, no one was able to reproduce this (at least, no one who commented) and you mentioned that it sorted itself out for you in May of this year. I'm marking this `status-norepro` and figuring that you just came across a tiny hiccup in the system.